# Выбрать всех потомков

Tags: дерево, php, база-данных, mysql

Если возможно, подскажите, как выбрать всех потомков (не только прямых) из структуры вида:

```
id|name|pid
20|Александр|17
24|Евгений|20
25|Максим|20
29|Станислав|25
30|Олег|16
32|Владислав|20
```

Т.е., при запросе потомков Александра должны быть выведены:

```
 - Евгений
 - Максим
 -- Станислав
```

Вложенность может быть неограниченной.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function ShowTree ($ParentID) {   
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `issue` WHERE `parent` = $ParentID";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);   
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo '<ul>';  
      // Здесь в цикле выводятся все "дети" у которых `parent` = $ParentID";
      // Вам нужно вывести что-то конкретное. Так выводите не всё, а то, что Вам нужно. Самое простое что можно предложить - делайте проверку внутри цикла.
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            if( ... ) echo "<li>".$row['name']."</li>";
            ShowTree ($row['id']);            
        }      
        echo '</ul>';
    }  
}

ShowTree (0);
```

Comment: Да, я в курсе на счет MySQL. Меня бы устроило решение на php.

Comment: google -> "mysql php рекурсивная выборка дерева" и будет Вам счастье=) Удачи тебе!

Comment: http://pastebin.com/98yFUqy2

Как модернизировать этот код, чтобы он выводил только ветвь, а не дерево?

Comment: Так что конкретно в  if( ... ) писать?

Comment: Ответ на поставленный Вами изначально вопрос: никаких условий ненужно. Программа выведет всё именно так, как написано у Вас в вопросе.

А что в if писать зависит от того, что за ветвь Вы хотите вывести. Я не могу дать Вам ответа на этот вопрос лишь потому что мне не знаком принцип выбора ветви.